# Can I use PnP PowerShell to set Conditional Access Policy on individual sites?

Tags: powershell, pnp

Using SharePoint Online Management Shell and `Set-SPOSite` I can set the Conditional Access Policy on individual OneDrive sites. Is it possible to do the same thing with PnP PowerShell? I can only find this setting on the tenant level cmdlet (`Set-PnPTenant`).

Since there is no way to use automation with SPO cmdlets when legacy authentication is disabled, I have to find another way to set this property.

Comment: Found any solutions to this? Have the exact same problem..

Comment: @Fredrik - have posted an answer to this question, can you try that out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported natively using the `Set-PnPTenantSite` commandlet, however you can use `Get-PnPTenantSite` commandlet to get the site collection object and then update it as per your requirement.

You can use it as below:

```
$context = Get-PnPContext
$site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
$site.ConditionalAccessPolicy = [Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.SPOConditionalAccessPolicyType]::AllowLimitedAccess
$site.Update()
$context.Load($site)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I used the method outlined [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Samples/SharePoint.ConnectUsingAppPermissions/ReadMe.md) to connect.